# Multiple choice questions in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am developing a webpage where i am going to conduct a small quiz based on plain JSP-MsAccess
connection.But when I run my quiz and when I answer a question the result is applied to all questions means if I get first question right then my score is 10 and if I get first answer wrong my score is 0.
code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 
String ans=" ";
if(request.getParameter("correctAns")!=null)
{
    ans=request.getParameter("correctAns").toString();
}


Connection conn = null;

Statement st = null;

ResultSet rs = null;

String id=request.getParameter("id");
System.out.println("id:"+id);

int i=1;

String s,g;

int count=0;

try {

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:qdsn");
 rs = null;

 st = conn.createStatement();

//for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
// {
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from exam");

while(rs.next()) {
%>


<br/>
<center>

<table border="1" width="500px" bgcolor="pink" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">

<form name="form1">

 <h2 align="center"><font color="red">Online Quiz Application</font></h2>

<b>Select Correct Answer</b>
        <table border="0" width="500px" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="4">
 <tr>

<td width="50%"> Question:</td>
<input type="hidden" name="correctAns" value="<%=rs.getString(6)%>" />
<tr>
<td><%= rs.getString("quest") %></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>

1: <input type="radio" name="a" value= "QA" /></td>
    <td><%= rs.getString("QA") %></td></tr> 
<tr>
<td>
2: <input type="radio" name="a" value="QB" /></td>
<td><%= rs.getString("QB") %></td></tr>

<tr>
<td>
3: <input type="radio" name="a" value="QC" /></td>
<td><%= rs.getString("QC") %> </td></tr>

<tr>
<td>
4: <input type="radio" name="a" value="QD" /> </td>
<td> <%= rs.getString("QD") %> </td></tr>

<tr>
<td>
<center>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></center></td></tr>
</table>

</form>
 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
<% g=request.getParameter("a");
%>
<% 
if(g.equals(ans)){

count++;
}

%>



<%
}}
// }
catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();

%>

<%
} finally {
if (rs != null) rs.close();
if (st != null) st.close();
if (conn != null) conn.close();
}
out.println("Score="+count);
%>


</html>
```

Comment: your question is not at all right.

Answer (score 1):

Update your radio button name to use some index i.e.

At the top side: declare the index variable.

```
<% int qNum = 0; %>
```

In middle of page, use the index variable in `radio` field naming.

```
 <input type="radio" name="a<%=qNum%>" value="QA" />
 <input type="radio" name="a<%=qNum%>" value="QB" />
 <input type="radio" name="a<%=qNum%>" value="QC" />
 <input type="radio" name="a<%=qNum%>" value="QD" />
```

In the bottom of the page, retrieve the index parameter and increase the index by one.

```
 <% g=request.getParameter("a"+qNum);
    qNum++;
  %>
```