# Generating Quiz questions with options using Map in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have a form for sending "question" to server.
A "question" has fields: title, description and options (from 1 to 4 represented by `Map<String, Boolean>`). String - for option, Boolean - true/false. 
So, how can I create a Map of every option **and send it to server**?

```
<div id="TYPE_TEST" class="opclass">
        <p><label for="option1"/>Option 1:
            <input id="option1" name="key" type="text" placeholder=""/>
            <input type="radio" name="value"/>
        </p>
        <p><label for="option2"/>Option 2:
            <input id="option2" name="key" type="text" placeholder=""/>
            <input type="radio" name="value"/>
        </p>
        <p><label for="option3"/>Option 3:
            <input id="option3" name="key" type="text" placeholder=""/>
            <input type="radio" name="value"/>
        </p>
        <p><label for="option4"/>Option 4:
            <input id="option4" name="key" type="text" placeholder=""/>
            <input type="radio" name="value"/>
        </p>
</div>
```

Thank you,
Pavel

Comment: You can go through this link for complete Quiz application creation from the scratch. [Creating Online Quiz using jsp](http://www.edureka.co/blog/creating-an-online-quiz-application-using-jsp-servlet/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to represent like this

represent questions and options like this

```
//Map<question,options>
//where option also map
    Map<String,Map<String,Boolean>> questions=new HashMap<String,Map<String,Boolean>>();
    Map<String,Boolean> question1_options=new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
            question1_options.put("option1",true);
    question1_options.put("option2",false);
    question1_options.put("option3",false);
    question1_options.put("option4",false);

    Map<String,Boolean> question2_options=new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
    question2_options.put("option1",true);
    question2_options.put("option2",false);
    question2_options.put("option3",false);
    question2_options.put("option4",false);

    questions.put("question_1",question1_options);
    questions.put("question_2",question2_options);
    System.out.println(questions);
```

Comment: I know how to do it in Java. But how to "bring" it from ***jsp*** to ***conroller***?

Comment: give a try of Paulo's snippet

Comment: OK, can u give me a link with some tutorial of this? I didnt google anything usefull. I believe that your answer is right but i dont know how to use it :/

Comment: Maybe this question related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995112/multiple-choice-questions-in-jsp

Answer (score 0):

Following MaDHaN's code: inside JSP, use it with `${mapName["option1"]}`.

If it works, I think MaDHaN deserves the accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways. Some of them as follows:

```
<%  Map<String,Boolean> map =new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
     map.put("key1",true);
     map.put("key2",false);
     request.setAttribute("map", map);
%>
 <%for(Map.Entry<String,Boolean> mapEntry: map.entrySet()){%>
    <%= mapEntry.getKey() %>
    <%= mapEntry.getValue() %>
 <%}%>
```

Or

```
 <c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    <c:out value ="${entry.key}" />
    <c:out value ="${entry.value}"/> 
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: with this code i can print my values. but i need to save them

Comment: above code shows how to save them in request scope.